# JQuery does not work but last element in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a web application for capturing applicant data. I am using JQuery for hiding and showing html tables. The code snippet is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function hideDD(){
var gndr = $('#gender').val();
if(gndr=="Female"){
$("#table_dd").hide();
$("#dd_bank").val('');
$("#dd_number").val('');
$("#dd_date").val('');
}
else
{   
     $("#table_dd").show();     
     }

var cat = $('#category').val();  
if(cat=="SC" || cat=="ST"){
$("#table_dd").hide();
$("#dd_bank").val('');
$("#dd_number").val('');
$("#dd_date").val('');
}
else
{   
     $("#table_dd").show();     
     }

var xsrv = $('#exsrv').val();
if(xsrv=="Yes"){
$("#table_dd").hide();
$("#dd_bank").val('');
$("#dd_number").val('');
$("#dd_date").val('');
}
else
{   
     $("#table_dd").show();     
     }
var PD = $('#PWDPH').val();
if(PD=="Yes"){
$("#table_dd").hide();
$("#dd_bank").val('');
$("#dd_number").val('');
$("#dd_date").val('');
}
else
{   
     $("#table_dd").show();     
     }
}
```

and the html part is

```
<tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">5. Gender :<span class="style2">*</span></td>
       <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="gender" id="gender" onclick="hideDD()">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
          </select>
            </td>   

            <!-- <div id="gender">
            Please select whichever is applicable to you <select name="gender" id="gender">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
          </select>
            </div> -->

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">6. Marital Status :<span class="style2">*</span></td>
       <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="maritalstatus" id="maritalstatus">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Married">Married</option>
            <option value="Unmarried">Unmarried</option>
            <option value="Widow">Widow</option>
            <option value="Divorced">Divorced</option>
            <option value="Judicially separated and not married">Judicially separated and not married</option>
          </select>
            </td>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">7. Date of Birth: <span class="style2">*</span></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="dateofbirth" type="text" id="dateofbirth" value="<?php echo "$rs1->dateofbirth" ?>" readonly /><span class="style2">(yyyy/mm/dd)</span>
        Your age(as on 31st July 2015):<input name="ageyear" type="text" id="ageyear" size="2" readonly>years<input name="agemonth" type="text" id="agemonth" size="2" readonly>months and<input name="ageday" type="text" id="ageday" size="2" readonly>days
            </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">8. Email:<span class="style2">*</span></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="afc_email" type="text" id="afc_email" value="<?php echo "$rs1->email" ?>" readonly />
            </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">9. Category :<span class="style2">*</span></td>
       <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="category" id="category" onclick="hideDD()">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="General">General</option>
            <option value="OBC">OBC</option>
            <option value="SC">SC</option>
            <option value="ST">ST</option>
          </select>
            </td>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">10 : You are a citizen of India by<span class="style2">*</span></td>
       <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="citizen" id="citizen">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Birth">Birth</option>
            <option value="Domicile">Domicile</option>
          </select>
            </td>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">11 : Religion<span class="style2">*</span></td>
       <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="religion" id="religion">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
            <option value="Muslims">Muslims</option>
            <option value="Christians">Christians</option>
            <option value="Sikhs">Sikhs</option>
            <option value="Buddhists">Buddhists</option>
            <option value="Zoroastrians">Zoroastrians</option>
             <option value="Others">Others</option>
          </select>
            </td>   
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">12 : Whether Ex-servicemen<span class="style2">*</span></td>
       <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="exsrv" id="exsrv" onclick="enb_dis(); hideDD()">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
          <table name="table_exserve" id="table_exserve" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>Have you already secured employment in civil side under central Govt. in Group C and D in regular basis after availing this benefit</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="exsrv_benefit" id="exsrv_benefit">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Date of appoinment in arm force</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="exsrv_from" type="text" id="exsrv_from" maxlength="10"/><span class="style2">(yyyy/mm/dd)</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Date of discharge / due date of discharge from arm force</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="exsrv_to" type="text" id="exsrv_to" maxlength="10" onchange="milical()"/><span class="style2">(yyyy/mm/dd)</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Length of actual Military services</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="miliyear" type="text" id="miliyear" size="2" readonly>years<input name="milimonth" type="text" id="milimonth" size="2" readonly>months and<input name="miliday" type="text" id="miliday" size="2" readonly>days</td>
        </tr>
          </table>        
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">13 : Whether person with disability(PWD) / Physically handicapped (PH)<span class="style2">*</span></td>
       <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="PWDPH" id="PWDPH" onclick="enb_dis(); hideDD()">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
          <table name="table_PWDPH" id="table_PWDPH" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>Nature of disability</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="PWDPH_nature" id="PWDPH_nature">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="LV">LV</option>
        <option value="PD">PD</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="OA">OA</option>
        <option value="OL">OL</option>
        <option value="BL">BL</option>
          </select> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Degree of disability</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><select name="PWDPH_degree" id="PWDPH_degree">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="41">41</option>
        <option value="42">42</option>
        <option value="43">43</option>
        <option value="44">44</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
        <option value="46">46</option>
        <option value="47">47</option>
        <option value="48">48</option>
        <option value="49">49</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="51">51</option>
        <option value="52">52</option>
        <option value="53">53</option>
        <option value="54">54</option>
        <option value="55">55</option>
        <option value="56">56</option>
        <option value="57">57</option>
        <option value="58">58</option>
        <option value="59">59</option>
        <option value="60">60</option>
        <option value="61">61</option>
        <option value="62">62</option>
        <option value="63">63</option>
        <option value="64">64</option>
        <option value="65">65</option>
        <option value="66">66</option>
        <option value="67">67</option>
        <option value="68">68</option>
        <option value="69">69</option>
        <option value="70">70</option>
        <option value="71">71</option>
        <option value="72">72</option>
        <option value="73">73</option>
        <option value="74">74</option>
        <option value="75">75</option>
        <option value="76">76</option>
        <option value="77">77</option>
        <option value="78">78</option>
        <option value="79">79</option>
        <option value="80">80</option>
        <option value="81">81</option>
        <option value="82">82</option>
        <option value="83">83</option>
        <option value="84">84</option>
        <option value="85">85</option>
        <option value="86">86</option>
        <option value="87">87</option>
        <option value="88">88</option>
        <option value="89">89</option>
        <option value="90">90</option>
        <option value="91">91</option>
        <option value="92">92</option>
        <option value="93">93</option>
        <option value="94">94</option>
        <option value="95">95</option>
        <option value="96">96</option>
        <option value="97">97</option>
        <option value="98">98</option>
        <option value="99">99</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>

    </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
          </table>        
      </tr>
```

Every time I did modification, the last jQuery item worked fine, rests did not work. For example in this code only `PWDPD` element worked fine, category and gender did not worked fine.

Comment: Try and get a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) semi working, so we can figure out where the problems may be in your code.

Comment: @Danbopes, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Function definition enb_dis() is missing in script and your are calling it on click event of element like this onclick="enb_dis(); hideDD()"

Comment: @Sunil Kumar, it is there and function dis_enb() is working fine. hideDD() is not working for gender, category and exsrv. it is only working for PWDPH element. That is the exact problem.

Comment: try onchange for <select> instead of onclick

Comment: I dont' find your element with id's `#table_dd`,`#dd_bank`, `#dd_number`, `#dd_date`? Can you please clarify on this??

Answer (score 1):

I've made several changes in your code like `<table>` tag was not not implemented properly and without that you had `<tr>` at beginning. So after editing all those things your code goes as below:

I've kept an alert inside your function which shows up on each element you have called that function and I've change `onclick` to `onchange` for your `select` element.

```js
function hideDD() {
    var gndr = $('#gender').val();
 alert(gndr);
 if(gndr=="Female"){
  $("#table_dd").hide();
  $("#dd_bank").val('');
  $("#dd_number").val('');
  $("#dd_date").val('');
 }
 else
 {   
  $("#table_dd").show();     
 }

 var cat = $('#category').val();  
 if(cat=="SC" || cat=="ST"){
  $("#table_dd").hide();
  $("#dd_bank").val('');
  $("#dd_number").val('');
  $("#dd_date").val('');
 }
 else
 {   
  $("#table_dd").show();     
 }

 var xsrv = $('#exsrv').val();
 if(xsrv=="Yes"){
  $("#table_dd").hide();
  $("#dd_bank").val('');
  $("#dd_number").val('');
  $("#dd_date").val('');
 }
 else
 {   
  $("#table_dd").show();     
 }
 
 var PD = $('#PWDPH').val();
 if(PD=="Yes"){
  $("#table_dd").hide();
  $("#dd_bank").val('');
  $("#dd_number").val('');
  $("#dd_date").val('');
 }
 else
 {   
  $("#table_dd").show();     
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">5. Gender :<span class="style2">*</span></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
   <select id="gender" onchange="hideDD()">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
   </select>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">6. Marital Status :<span class="style2">*</span></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
   <select name="maritalstatus" id="maritalstatus">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
    <option value="Unmarried">Unmarried</option>
    <option value="Widow">Widow</option>
    <option value="Divorced">Divorced</option>
    <option value="Judicially separated and not married">Judicially separated and not married</option>
   </select>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">7. Date of Birth: <span class="style2">*</span></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="dateofbirth" type="text" id="dateofbirth" value="<?php echo "$rs1->dateofbirth" ?>" readonly />
   <span class="style2">(yyyy/mm/dd)</span>
        Your age(as on 31st July 2015):<input name="ageyear" type="text" id="ageyear" size="2" readonly>years<input name="agemonth" type="text" id="agemonth" size="2" readonly>months and<input name="ageday" type="text" id="ageday" size="2" readonly>days
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">8. Email:<span class="style2">*</span></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="afc_email" type="text" id="afc_email" value="<?php echo "$rs1->email" ?>" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">9. Category :<span class="style2">*</span></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
   <select name="category" id="category" onchange="hideDD()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="General">General</option>
    <option value="OBC">OBC</option>
    <option value="SC">SC</option>
    <option value="ST">ST</option>
   </select>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">10 : You are a citizen of India by<span class="style2">*</span></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
   <select name="citizen" id="citizen">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Birth">Birth</option>
    <option value="Domicile">Domicile</option>
   </select>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">11 : Religion<span class="style2">*</span></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
   <select name="religion" id="religion">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
    <option value="Muslims">Muslims</option>
    <option value="Christians">Christians</option>
    <option value="Sikhs">Sikhs</option>
    <option value="Buddhists">Buddhists</option>
    <option value="Zoroastrians">Zoroastrians</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
   </select>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">12 : Whether Ex-servicemen<span class="style2">*</span></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
   <select name="exsrv" id="exsrv" onchange="hideDD()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
   </select>
   <table name="table_exserve" id="table_exserve" border="1">
    <tr>
     <td>Have you already secured employment in civil side under central Govt. in Group C and D in regular basis after availing this benefit</td>
     <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
      <select name="exsrv_benefit" id="exsrv_benefit">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
       <option value="No">No</option>
      </select> 
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Date of appoinment in arm force</td>
     <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="exsrv_from" type="text" id="exsrv_from" maxlength="10"/><span class="style2">(yyyy/mm/dd)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Date of discharge / due date of discharge from arm force</td>
     <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="exsrv_to" type="text" id="exsrv_to" maxlength="10" onchange="milical()"/><span class="style2">(yyyy/mm/dd)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Length of actual Military services</td>
     <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5"><input name="miliyear" type="text" id="miliyear" size="2" readonly>years<input name="milimonth" type="text" id="milimonth" size="2" readonly>months and<input name="miliday" type="text" id="miliday" size="2" readonly>days</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">13 : Whether person with disability(PWD) / Physically handicapped (PH)<span class="style2">*</span></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
   <select name="PWDPH" id="PWDPH" onchange="hideDD();">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
   </select>
   <table name="table_PWDPH" id="table_PWDPH" border="1">
    <tr>
     <td>Nature of disability</td>
     <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
      <select name="PWDPH_nature" id="PWDPH_nature">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="B">B</option>
       <option value="LV">LV</option>
       <option value="PD">PD</option>
       <option value="D">D</option>
       <option value="OA">OA</option>
       <option value="OL">OL</option>
       <option value="BL">BL</option>
      </select> 
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Degree of disability</td>
     <td bgcolor="#FFF3D5">
      <select name="PWDPH_degree" id="PWDPH_degree">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="40">40</option>
       <option value="41">41</option>
       <option value="42">42</option>
       <option value="43">43</option>
       <option value="44">44</option>
       <option value="45">45</option>
       <option value="46">46</option>
       <option value="47">47</option>
       <option value="48">48</option>
       <option value="49">49</option>
       <option value="50">50</option>
       <option value="51">51</option>
       <option value="52">52</option>
       <option value="53">53</option>
       <option value="54">54</option>
       <option value="55">55</option>
       <option value="56">56</option>
       <option value="57">57</option>
       <option value="58">58</option>
       <option value="59">59</option>
       <option value="60">60</option>
       <option value="61">61</option>
       <option value="62">62</option>
       <option value="63">63</option>
       <option value="64">64</option>
       <option value="65">65</option>
       <option value="66">66</option>
       <option value="67">67</option>
       <option value="68">68</option>
       <option value="69">69</option>
       <option value="70">70</option>
       <option value="71">71</option>
       <option value="72">72</option>
       <option value="73">73</option>
       <option value="74">74</option>
       <option value="75">75</option>
       <option value="76">76</option>
       <option value="77">77</option>
       <option value="78">78</option>
       <option value="79">79</option>
       <option value="80">80</option>
       <option value="81">81</option>
       <option value="82">82</option>
       <option value="83">83</option>
       <option value="84">84</option>
       <option value="85">85</option>
       <option value="86">86</option>
       <option value="87">87</option>
       <option value="88">88</option>
       <option value="89">89</option>
       <option value="90">90</option>
       <option value="91">91</option>
       <option value="92">92</option>
       <option value="93">93</option>
       <option value="94">94</option>
       <option value="95">95</option>
       <option value="96">96</option>
       <option value="97">97</option>
       <option value="98">98</option>
       <option value="99">99</option>
       <option value="100">100</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>        
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try place you code inside:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    YOUR CODE HERE
});
```